# Запретить масштабирование в обозревателе

Tags: gwt, javascript, html, css, обозреватель

Как запретить масштабирование страницы в обозревателе? Конкретно на андроиде. Также интересует кросс-браузерное решение.

Comment: Блокирование функций - преступление по отношению к пользователю. Если у вас есть проблемы с разметкой - лучше решите их.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте между <head>...</head> такой вот тэг:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score -2):

Кроссбраузерно: либо все значения выставлять в процентах, либо сделать блеклую приписочку внизу страницы: "просьба не масштабировать сайт - фигня может случиться".
А также можно попробовать отлавливать нажатия клавиш и, в случае комбинации для масштабирования, отменять событие.